# Column 'client_id' cannot be null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am trying to run:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

And it is returning me this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'client_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into
> `oauth_personal_access_clients` (`client_id`, `updated_at`,
> `created_at`) values (, 2022-11-0     8 07:58:48, 2022-11-08
> 07:58:48))

I am on laravel 5.5 with php 7.1. What am I doing wrong here? Passport version is 2.0.4.

Comment: What is the version of passport you're using?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi eustion updated with passport version.

Comment: Checking it here, I see this version coming up: `composer require laravel/passport=~4.0`. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#main-content

Comment: Yes my laravel is 5.5 but I am using passport for laravel 5.3 as I forked the passport as I had some other needs which laravel passport didn't come up with by default.

Comment: Typically this Error means that your field `client_id` is not nullable and while executing this query client_id is not passing in value parameters.

Comment: So you might have extended the Passport trait? If so, check for the fillable properties and just add the default values.

Comment: Try running `php artisan passport:install -vvv` to see if there are any additional errors that are shown that might give a hint as to what might have gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below bullet points according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport) instructions for laravel 5:

1. To get started, install Passport via the Composer package manager:

   **composer require laravel/passport=~4.0**
2. The Passport service provider registers its own database migration directory with the framework, so you should migrate your database after registering the provider. The Passport migrations will create the tables your application needs to store clients and access tokens:

   **php artisan migrate**
3. Next, you should run the passport:install command. This command will create the encryption keys needed to generate secure access tokens. In addition, the command will create "personal access" and "password grant" clients which will be used to generate access tokens:

   **php artisan passport:install**